# Getting Lat/Long in center of the map in Mapview

Tags: android, get, location, mapbox

I have a project in Android Studio. I added a Mapview to show a Mapbox map. I need to get Lat/Long of map center point when user touches the button.

Would you please help me to solve problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

This will give you the latitude and longitude of center of the map.

Comment: Here is the [relevant API documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/8.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/camera/CameraPosition.html) for the latest release, just to confirm that this is correct.